# Query different levels in database laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Good day. Am trying to query my database to get the child of a child of a child. Every user has 2 children. Am using query builder. The requirements is not to use eloquent and eloquent relationships. But am struggling with it.

```
$firstchild= DB::table('users') - >where('parent_id',  Auth::user() ->id) -> get() ;
$secondchild1 = DB::table('users') - >where('parent_id',  $firstchild[0]->parent_id) ->  get() ;
$secondchild2 = DB::table('users') - >where('parent_id',  $firstchild[1]parent_id) -> get() ;
return view('home' ['firstchild' => $firstchild, 'secondchild1 ' => $secondchild1, 'secondchild2 ' => $secondchild2 , ])
```

It returns undefined offset 0 if the user child has no child. How do i do it if i want to get without any errors.

If I want to get the children of those children the query results gave, how will I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$firstchild = DB::table('users')->where('parent_id',  Auth::user()->id)->get();

if ($firstchild->count() == 2) {  //**Contains exactly 2 arrays inside the 'firstchild' collection.
    $secondchild1 = DB::table('users')->where('parent_id', $firstchild[0]->parent_id)->get();
    $secondchild2 = DB::table('users')->where('parent_id', $firstchild[1]->parent_id)->get();
}

return view('home', compact('firstchild', 'secondchild1', 'secondchild2'));
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Though if the person has only one child it would return undefined offset 1.

Comment: Though I would be appreciative if you showeed me how to get the child of a child and the child of that child

Comment: Show your DB schema

Comment: Each user has a parent_id and then  a id field.